# NSImageViewl Highlighting/Selection

Tags: macos, nsimageview

(using Xcode 8b0 on 10.11.5, but the problem also occurs under 7.3)

My app uses an NSColorWell and two NSImageWells to allow users to set a background (colour, image, pattern). The colourWell behaves just fine. The two image wells do not: if you click on one, it will be selected and it is impossible to deselect both (which is what I want if I am using the colourWell.)

NSImageView does not have a deactivate or deselect method. isHighlighted is false even when the imageWell is clearly marked as selected; setting the highlight on either the imageWell or its cell has no visual effect.

The memory of selection persists even between restarts of the app which makes me think it must be stored in the storyboard somehow, only I cannot work out which property is responsible (I've read through the documentation for NSImageView and NSControl without luck).

By employing a ridiculous dance of disabling and enabling my image wells in specific order (you need to enable the one you want to show up as selected first) combined with subclassing NSImageView to override 'mouseDown' so it sends a notification that I capture to trigger the imageWell's action I have got the behaviour I want, but I would really appreciate an easier way of doing this since 'enable/disable controls in specific order' feels like a hack. (So, alas, feels adding the appropriate drag-and-drop support to a NSButton; I really *like* the 'drop image, have background change' functionality).

Who or what is causing my NSImageViews to be highlighted and how can I take control of this behaviour?

[image: Screenshot illustrating unwanted highlight]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that this is not a highlight, which is why setting isHighlighted to false does nothing at all. NSImageView has a property named `allowsCutCopyPaste`- and if this is set to 'true', the imageWell - or the currently active imageWell if you have more than one - will show this 'highlight'.